# Vertical "isomorphic to" symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

How might I create a sequence with vertical "isomorphic to" symbols as in the following picture?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already have the solution in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/321997/10995) to [your other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321987).

Here a more generalised approach with the newly defined `ar symbol`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  ar symbol/.style = {draw=none,"#1" description,sloped},
  isomorphic/.style = {ar symbol={\cong}},
  equals/.style = {ar symbol={=}},
  ]
  A \ar[r] & B \ar[r] & C \ar[r,equals] & D \\
  \mathbb{Z}_{?} \ar[u,isomorphic] & \mathbb{Z}_{12} \ar[u,isomorphic] & \mathbb{Z}_{24} \ar[u,isomorphic] \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Further discussion in the chat, resulted in this optimal solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  column sep=tiny,row sep=small,
  ar symbol/.style = {draw=none,"\textstyle#1" description,sloped},
  isomorphic/.style = {ar symbol={\cong}},
  ]
  A \ar[r]                         & B \ar[r]                          & C \mathrlap{{} = D}               \\
  \mathbb{Z}_{?} \ar[u,isomorphic] & \mathbb{Z}_{12} \ar[u,isomorphic] & \mathbb{Z}_{24} \ar[u,isomorphic] \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If the distances are too large for you, try the additional option `sep=small`.

Comment: Right, thank you very much. Is there a way to stretch the \cong? It comes out really small for me

Comment: Where would I add sep=small?

Comment: @iwriteonbananas You don't want to stretch the symbol.  This will look weird and people might mistake it for something else.  As you can see I also have not stretched the equal sign.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. :)

Comment: @iwriteonbananas Before you ask for every little piece of configuration here, I highly suggest that you read the [`tikz-cd` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf).  It is short (17 pages), has many examples, and surely contains all the solutions you are looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43367/discussion-between-henri-menke-and-iwriteonbananas).

Comment: does the direction of rotation of this symbol make a difference?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Because this is a relational symbol you can flip the operand without changing the meaning, just like `1+1 = 2` is equivalent to `2 = 1+1`.  I would still suggest that if you would write `A \cong B` then use ``B \\ A \ar[u,isomorphic] \\`` instead of ``B \ar[d,isomorphic] \\ A \\``

Answer (score 2):

I propose another `isom` symbol (and rotated variants thereof), based an the `\AC`  symbol from `wasysym`, and the `stackengine` package. Theuy might be used in non-tkz contexts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage{wasysym, stackengine, makebox, graphicx}

\newcommand\isom{\mathrel{\stackon[-0.1ex]{\makebox*{\scalebox{1.08}{\AC}}{=\hfill\llap{=}}}{{\AC}}}}
\newcommand\nvisom{\rotatebox[origin=cc] {-90}{$ \isom $}}
\newcommand\visom{\rotatebox[origin=cc] {90} {$ \isom $}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[sep = small]
  A \ar[r] & B \ar[r] & C \ar[r ,equals] & D \\
  \mathbb{Z}_{?} \ar[u, phantom, "\visom"] & \mathbb{Z}_{12} \ar[u,phantom, "\nvisom"] \ar[r, phantom, "\isom"] & \mathbb{Z}_{24} \ar[u, phantom, "\nvisom"] \\
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]